# How do I handle orientation changes in the presenting UIViewController when using a custom transition

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController as the root view controller that presents another UIViewController using a custom transition. When you rotate the device while looking at the child view controller, then go back to the root view controller, the root view controller's view frame isn't updated. I've narrowed it down to the presence of a custom transition, i.e. if you don't have a custom transition, it works just fine. What would be the best way to have the custom transition and have the root view controller handle orientation changes appropriately?

I have a demo project available here: https://github.com/rawbee/TestOrientation

Comment: The problem is that you've written your transition wrong. You are using exactly the same transition for `present` and for `dismiss`, with no change — that is, your transition doesn't distinguish between which this is. That's wrong. It needs to do completely opposite things in the two different cases!

Comment: @matt What about it needs to be different, in both cases, I would just like to fade out the from view controller to reveal the destination view controller.

Comment: @rawbee you've just forgotten to set the frame for the new view controller, see my answer

Comment: The difference is that in the two different cases the `to` view controller and the `from` view controller are _reversed_. You are failing to take account of that fact.

Comment: @matt, I thought the fact that they were reversed allowed for the transition to be re-used. i.e. for present; from == root (currently showing), to == child, and for dismiss, from == child (currently showing), to == parent. So in both cases, the transition would fade out the currently showing view controller. Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @matt I don't see any problem in the way he approaches it, if the transition is the same.. why would he implement the same transition twice?

Comment: I guess this was a fullscreen presentation so it happens that it didn't matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you just forgotten to set the frame for the view controller that is being presented:

```
toVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame
```

Just add this line to `animateTransition` so that the method looks like this:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
        let snapshot = fromVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
        else { return }

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    // you want the newly presented view to have the same frame as the old one
    toVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame

    containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
    containerView.addSubview(snapshot)

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), curve: .easeInOut) {
        snapshot.alpha = 0.0
    }
    animator.addCompletion { _ in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```